# What is the mean average of $y=kg^t$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$

Tags: mean, growth-model, calculus

Mean average of $y$ in $y=kg^t$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$.

$g$ is a constant, $t$ varies.

I have looked this up in textbooks and online and all I can find is the mean average of a function where $t$ is a constant and $g$ is variable. But that is not what I want.

Some approximation clearly shows that the mean average is not the value of the mid-point where $t=(a+b)/2$.

My calculus is too basic to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $g>0$ (because otherwise this does not make sense).

The mean is usually defined as the number $\bar{y}$ such that
$$ (b-a)\bar{y} = \int_a^b kg^t\,dt $$
(i.e., the rectangle with height $\bar{y}$ has the same area as there is under your function, in both cases betwee $t=a$ and $t=b$), or
$$ \bar{y} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b kg^t\,dt. $$
[WolframAlpha is a good place for such integrals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+k*g%5Et+from+t%3Da+to+t%3Db):
$$ \bar{y} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b kg^t\,dt=\frac{1}{b-a}
\frac{k(g^b - g^a)}{\log(g)}. $$

Comment: Thanks. But why is log(g) used rather than, for example, ln(g)?

Comment: Now I see that for WolframAlpha, log(g) means the natural log.